# How to share one Express session with Redis store between two same app

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis

I have a simple Express app with session store like

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'some',
  key: 'smt',
  store: new redisStore(redisStoreConfig),
  proxy: 'true',
  resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

When i try launch this app two or more times for increase app performance, my clients miss authorisation after login.
I what way i could share session between some app instances?

Comment: From my limited understanding, you should be able to connect multiple express applications to the same instance of redis. Can you clarify exactly where the problem is? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: my clients have miss authorisation after login. Another one - all Express instances is operating by Nginx, may be a bottle neck is here

Comment: I don't think Nginx will be causing the issue because your express instance should directly connect to the redis instance without having to go through the reverse proxy. My recommendation would be to use `redis-cli` to test if your redis instance is accessible from both your express app instances. (I'm assuming the two express app and redis server are all running on independent instances/systems)

Comment: Are the session cookies being received by both applications? If they're on different domains then the chances are they probably won't be. Sharing cookies isn't a great idea, so you'll need to make sure they're under the same domain or share sessions in some other way.